# Searching keywords in title

Tags: vba, excel

Im using the below code for seacrhing a set of keywords in a cell which has title. While running the code im getting "Run Time error 13" Type mismatch on **b = cell.Value** line.

```js
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim col As Range, cell1 As Range, a As String, b As String, i As Integer
Set col = Range("KW[KW1]")
Dim target, cell As Range
Sheets("Data").Select
Set target = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
Dim term, tag As String
    For Each cell1 In col
    a = cell1.Value

    term = a
    tag = a

        For Each cell In target
           b = cell.Value
           ' If InStr(1, " " & cell & " ", " " & term & " ", 1) Then
          If Module1.ExactWordInString(b, a) Then
                For i = 1 To 15
                    If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, i).Value = tag
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

        End If

        Next cell
    Next cell1
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However its running perfectly if we have 1000 tiltes in a column, but i want to run this code for a massive range upto 50,000 to 200,000. Please help me.

Comment: Where do you get the run time error as in on which line?

Comment: On which line of instructions, do you have the type mismatch?

Comment: on line "b = cell.Value" im getting the error message @izzymo and R3uK

Comment: Interesting and you get this error only when you run for 50,000 to 200,000 columns and not when you run for just 1000 columns?

Comment: Yes, if i run this for more than 1000+ @izzymo im really confused :(

Comment: Can you try using msgBox Cell.Value after the current line b = Cell.Value after you get that error so we can see what the contents of the particular error causing cell are.

Comment: Yes i tried it now im getting error in line If "Module1.ExactWordInString(b, a) Then" PFB respective function


Function ExactWordInString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
     ExactWordInString = " " & UCase(Text) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(Word) & "[!A-Z]*"
End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you didn't declare target as a range, might be it.

BTW, when you compare string VBA is case sensitive, so try to use Lcase() if you only want to compare content!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim target  As Range, cell As Range
Dim term As String, tag As String
Dim col As Range, cell1 As Range, a As String, b As String, i As Integer

Sheets("Data").Select
Set col = Range("KW[KW1]")
Set target = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B65536").End(xlUp))


For Each cell1 In col
    a = Cstr(cell1.Value)
    term = a
    tag = a
    For Each cell In target
        b = Cstr(cell.Value)
        'If InStr(1, " " & cell & " ", " " & term & " ", 1) Then
        If Module1.ExactWordInString(b, a) Then
            For i = 1 To 15
                If cell.Offset(0, i).Value = "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, i).Value = tag
                Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next cell
Next cell1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks @R3uk but im still getting the same error message on line "b = cell.Value"

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but do you have some numerical or strange value that would like to be put in a string?

Comment: Yes @R3uk there are some values in th erange like 14 carat yellow, 6 lights, Sizes range from 7 3.. etc. Sorry i haven't checked it before, what should i do now

Comment: Thanks @R3uk the macro is running now but it will take time to check it completely. Will get back to you once i have done the complete check :).

Could you please tell me, what will Cstr() function do exactly?

Comment: Great! Cstr() just take a variable and convert it to a String, you also have CDate, CDbl (double), ... And don't forget that VBA is case sensitive so TeST<>test and INStr won't find it, Lcase() everything you test when it's not Case sensitive! Enjoy!